# Получить из строки все части совпадения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Надо из `"something $1 $2 $999 another..."` получить массив `[1, 2, 999]`

`/\$\d+/g` находит то что надо, но необходимо из результата исключить `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте захватывающую подмаску `(...)` - `/\$(\d+)/g`:

```js
var s = "something $1 $2 $999 another...";
var res=[], m;
var rx = /\$(\d+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/lULiiB/1).

**Подробности**:

- `\$` - символ `$`
- `(\d+)`  - захватывающая подмаска №1, находит 1 и более (благодаря квантификатору `+`) цифр (`\d` находит цифры).

Comment: В C# можно так: `Regex.Matches(s, @"\$([0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`